# Change height of a listbox as when the scrollviewer is scrolled

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, listbox, scrollviewer

I have a listbox inside a scrollviewer and i want to change the height of the listbox when i scroll up/down. The height of the listbox should increase when i scroll down and vice versa

here's how i am doing it :

```
private void OnScrollbarValueChanged(object sender,RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        listbox.Height += e.NewValue - e.OldValue;       
    }
```

However this is serving my purpose,but appears to be lagging alot. There's alot of stutter while i scroll and the height changes. Anyway to let go of the stutter/lag and make this change in height lag free?

Comment: are you trying to achieve something like parallax effect?

Comment: I think you could achieve smoothness by using Storyboard and DoubleAnimation.

Comment: @SeeSharp -  yes indeed! Although, parallax effect has been integrated with no stutters, the difficulty now is having a textbox at the bottom of the page which should always remain there, even if the keyboard shows up. And manipulating the height of the Listbox. The parallax is there on top of the ListBox where lies an image.

Answer (score 0):

So i found an [example](http://y2bd.me/blog/2014/03/18/creating-a-parallax-scrolling-effect-on-windows-phone/) how to achieve parallax effect in windows phone, and i modify it slightly.

Here is the XML, i think it's exactly what you are going for.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid x:Name="ImageContainer"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          CacheMode="BitmapCache"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="ImageTransform" />
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Image Source="/Assets/chitanda.jpg"
               Stretch="None"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               x:Name="Image" />
        </Grid>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller" Margin="0,300,0,0"
                  ManipulationMode="Control"
                  Background="#33000000">
            <Grid x:Name="ScrollGrid" Margin="0,-300,0,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="500" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        Margin="0,0,0,24">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"
                           Margin="24,0"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Text="Title" />
                </StackPanel>
                <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Static TextBox on the bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I order to avoid a conflict in the scrolling i disable it in the ListBox. The code-behind is absolutely the same. I hope this is what you are looking for. Happy coding (:

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but i am not looking for this behavior, I also found the same blog but i have modified the xaml as per my own needs